# Count a visit mysql error image host clickjack

Tags: php, mysql, image

Hi i have a web that pays people according to their views of their images hosted on my site. The problem is the users have managed to clickjack the system by commenting on bulletin boards the links(not the direct links to the image but to the viewer) in this way [IMG]link[IMG]. So the users are credited with visits of people that do not enter my site.

The code to add a visit to the mysql table is this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE images SET img_views = '$views++' WHERE id = '$id'");
```

Do you have any idea how can i fix this? for example an IF condition?

I will be really thanked

Comment: BTW you can do: `UPDATE images SET img_views = img_views+1 WHERE id = '$id'`

Comment: Really the only way is to have the user log into your system before viewing the image or not count the image as viewed if its not viewed from within your site. This will discourage abusers and perhaps stop future ddos :p

Answer (score 0):

Use an php page to serve the image. in that php page check the referer URI if it matches with your domain then serve the page. you can put your image outside of webroot to prevent direct access to your image.

```
if(pathinfo($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])['host']==$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'])
{
header("content-type:image:/png")
readfile("/location/to your/image/which/is/outside/webroot/image.png")
//Run update script for visit count
}
else
{
//send access denied header
}
```